# REST message security (end-to-end security)

Tags: rest, web-services, security, authentication, restful-authentication

What are most common ways to implement end-to-end message security (authentication and encryption) on REST services?

I could use TLS and basic authentication for point-to-point communication, but this really doesn't provide end-to-end security, as an attacker could be the administrator of the load balancer for example.

SOAP have WS-Security to provide end-to-end security. What is the REST alternative?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be completely independent of possibly hostile intermediates (like a TLS termination you mention in your question) you should aim at encrypting the data the user is going to access with his credentials, and encrypt/decrypt them client side.

This way, whatever happens on the way would leak, at most, a binary blob.